# Core Isolation Issue: "Kernel-mode Hardware-enforced Stack Protection is off"

Tags: security, windows-11

I am getting this warning since my last Windows 11 update in:

- Windows Security > Device Security > Core Isolation

> Kernel-mode Hardware-enforced Stack Protection is off. Your device may be vulnerable.

The option to enable it is greyed out so I cannot enable it.

There is a red text above it that states:

> This setting is managed by your administrator.

I am the only user on the computer and my user is an an admin user. This is a Windows 11 Pro.

It is a very recent machine and Intel CPU and all virtualization settings are all and Hyper-V is installed and working.

How can I enable this setting?

Why does it say that the option is controlled by my administrator?

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the WinInit event logs as described in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1782343/local-security-authority-protection-missing-from-settings-device-security-core/1782349#1782349) answer.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why, but it looks like it should be setup through group policies `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Guard`. From what I read on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/hardware-security/enable-virtualization-based-protection-of-code-integrity it looks like incorrect setup can caused problems. It's possible that this option is not automatically enabled in case there are some compatibility issues. Also, from what I understand this is replacement of LSA, which had a lot of issues at launch, so maybe some of them transferred to the new feature.

Comment: The user isn't using a group policy to manage this setting.

Comment: Yet, for me enabling it through group policy removed the "managed by administrator" notice and actually enabled the feature. Or at least it is shown as enabled now.

Comment: Seems like you had a different issue. I suspect I know the reason which is the reason I have doubts this solution would help the author.

Comment: that's a possibility. LSA also had lots of issues when it was initially implemented, varying from system to system. Since this feature is replacing LSA (or more like "superseding"), it's possible that it also has a plethora of possible issues.

Comment: It’s not a recent replacement. We are talk years.

Comment: I am not sure about years. LSA appeared for me maybe at the beginning of 2023.