# New Windows install, Tamper Protection disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

So I have bought a used computer which in general works as intended. But when I did a fresh install of Windows 10 22H2 from USB, and before making any changes or downloading any AV, I noticed that Windows Defender’s Tamper Protection was off. There was no problem enabling it manually, but as far as I know this is always enabled by default with new installs. I verified this by installing a VM with the same ISO and just as expected the VM had Tamper Protection turned on when starting Windows. I then reinstalled Windows (non-virtualized) from USB again and TP was off on startup just as before.

I’m interested to hear your thoughts as to why this could occur when installing Windows, and if there is any reason to be wary of the second hand hardware?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you are seeing exactly?  I suspect I know exactly what is going on[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1782343/local-security-authority-protection-missing-from-settings-device-security-core/1782349#1782349)

Comment: Affirmative, updated with a link to the screenshot.

Comment: Microsoft recently released updated Windows 10 22H2 ISOs to address an unrelated issue.  When you performed the fresh install.  You formatted the HDD and then reinstalled Windows, or you performed what is commonly referred to as a clean install and selected the option not to keep anything?

Comment: I formatted the SSD and reinstalled Windows, from a bootable USB made with Media Creation Tool earlier today.

Comment: Tamper protection is ON here: Windows 10 Pro and Windows 11 Pro. Standard install, nothing special done. One machine is a virtual machine, the rest are real machines. The VM made the way you did it.

Comment: I should add that, if I let Windows Update run, Tamper Protection turns on. It's only after a fresh Windows install that it is disabled.

Comment: @tafferburrick - If installing an update from Windows Update, turns Tamper Protection on, then you have identified the reason it was turned off.  What build did you install exactly before you updated the installation?

Comment: Perhaps on the VM install you had Windows updates installing while setting it up, and on the physical install not?

Comment: @Ramhound - I've been using build 19045

Comment: you had Windows updates installing while setting it up, and on the physical install not?    No. Standard installs and I always update.

Comment: Standard installation with OOBE has a step for installing updates, and after updates it's on for OP as well. But maybe in his case for the physical install he either wasn't connected to a network yet, or skipped that (which is why the physical install didn't have TP On yet.)

Comment: @YisroelTech - That's a good point, perhaps Windows updates itself during install? I did have internet during most of the install of VM, but not when installing to computer.

Comment: @John - Yes, could be this. I will probably try physical install again with internet connected this time. I usually remove the ethernet cable just to not be bothered with Microsoft sign-in.

Comment: Then it's most certainly this. Test and let know.

Comment: @YisroelTech - I tried the opposite scenario, installing Windows to VM while offline and installing to computer connected to the internet. But the same thing happens. VM has Tamper Protection enabled from the get-go while the physical install still does not. For VM, I used a new .iso downloaded with Media Creation Tool and for the physical install I created a new USB with the same tool. 

Maybe this could either be (1) related to my computer or (2) Media Creation Tool creates a more updated .iso file compared to when it creates a bootable USB (perhaps for using with offline computers)?

Comment: The Media Creation Tool does do updates as well as part of the creation. How about (for both scenarios) try an ISO download (the last option https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) or how about trying to create a bootable USB from the same ISO you used for the VM creation using a tool like Rufus.

Comment: I have now used Rufus to create a bootable USB from the exact same .ISO file that I installed to VM. Regardless if I'm offline or online, TP is disabled when first starting up the physical computer but enabled in the VM. So maybe it can be concluded that some hardware issue or incompatibility between Windows and hardware hinders TP from turning on automatically at install / start, and that this is not the case with the VMWare virtual hardware and drivers? Using an AMD AM4 system.

Comment: And a Windows update (on the PC with hardware issue or incompatibility) fixes it? Unlikely.

Comment: You’re right, but Windows update just fixes so that TP automatically turns on, I can still enable it manually even before updating. I was able to try an old Intel system, just reusing the SSD, GPU and RAM from the new computer. Behavior was the same, so at least it has been shown to be unrelated to motherboard / CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a conclusion after testing with three separate computers and three different USB sticks. There appears to be an issue with **Windows 10 build 19045**, when installing this from a USB made with either Media Creation Tool or Rufus to a newly formated disk, where **Tamper Protection** gets disabled by default. This is the case regardless if the computer has an internet connection or not. Applying updates enables TP and it's also possible to enable it manually. The problem is not replicated when using an .iso to install to a VM, only when installing non-virtualized from USB.

One solution to this was using the older **build 19044** installed the same way from USB, then Tamper Protection is enabled by default. Another option is to use Windows 11 which as of current build also enables TP from the start.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the facts that:

1. After Windows Updates running it turns on automatically on this machine
2. You had the machine disconnected from the network while installing (and the VM installation did have network while installing)

I think that the explanation is that ***Tamper Protection*** actually comes Off on Windows installation, and gets turned On by the Windows Updates (/Defender Updates).

Typically, on the Windows installation OOBE (Out of Box Experience) Windows Updates is run as part of the setup, which caused the VM install to have it enabled. While on the main machone install you disconnected the network so updates weren't able to run, hence it remained disabled until you ran updates after installation.